# Module '"../../../../@types/parse5"' has no exported member 'DefaultTreeElement'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When attempting to build an angular app, this error comes up:

```
node_modules/@angular/cdk/schematics/utils/html-manipulation.d.ts:9:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../../@types/parse5"' has no exported member 'DefaultTreeElement'.

Angular 11.2.14 
Angular CLI: 11.2.13
Node: 14.17.0
```

[image]

I'm working with 4 more people using the same app and nobody is having this problem. 
I've tried the following solutions that didn't work:

- Delete the entire app and clone it back in from git.
- Clear the node_modules and install it all over again.
- Updated Node.js (to the current one)
- Updated npm (to the current one)
- Updated Angular CLI (to the current one)
- Installed @types/parse5 (using npm install @types/parse5)

In between every of these I did a npm cache clean -f

This is how the package.json is right now:

```
{
  "name": "rferp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.5",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/rrule": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.4.0",
    "@ngrx/component-store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/bingmaps": "0.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.33",
    "@types/parse5": "^6.0.0",
    "azure-maps-control": "^2.0.32",
    "azure-maps-drawing-tools": "^0.1.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "clone": "^2.1.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-azure-maps": "^4.0.0",
    "parse5": "^6.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.2.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.4.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rrule": "^2.6.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.34.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "typescript": "4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome :) 
Do you have a different OS from the other guys?

Comment: No. We all have Windows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, suddenly a few days ago.
Also using Angular 11.

Somehow the parse5 package was updated to version 6.0.1, I think, because reverting back to 5.0.0 fixed it.